# How to determine whether my docbook file is valid?

Tags: docbook

I have a docbook file `me.xml`. I keep getting errors when I attempt to convert it to pdf, and I'm not sure whether the converter or my file is the problem.

Is there a quick, failsafe way that I can test whether my file is correct-formatted docbook?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to know if it is a Docbook 5.x or DocBook 4.5.

Docbook 4.5 sample header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE article PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.5//EN"
"http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.5/docbookx.dtd">
<article>
  <articleinfo>
    <title/>

    <author>
      <firstname/>

      <surname/>

      <affiliation>
        <orgname/>
      </affiliation>
    </author>

    <pubdate/>
  </articleinfo>

  <section>
    <title/>

    <para/>
  </section>
</article>
```

DocBook 5.1 sample header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter version="5.1"
  xmlns="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xila="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude/local-attributes"
  xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
  xmlns:trans="http://docbook.org/ns/transclusion"
  xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
  xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:db="http://docbook.org/ns/docbook">
  <info>
    <title>Introduction</title>
  </info>
  <section>
    <info>
      <title>Chapter title</title>
    </info>
    <para>
    You can see an example:
    </para>
    <example>
    <title>main example</title>
      <programlisting language="c">
      </programlisting>
    </example>
  </section>
</chapter>
```

### How to validate:

1. In case you use editor to create/edit your DocBook files (like [XMLMind XML Editor](http://www.xmlmind.com/xmleditor/) or [Oxygen Author](https://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_author.html)) - it is fully editor's responsibility to make a validation and tell you if you have an error in your DocBook document. Moreover editor just don't allow you to make a wrong element inserts.
2. In case you just have `xml` file and/or create in in any text editor - you need tools to validate it against schema in a command line.

   - for DocBook 4.5 you can validate against DocBook DTD using `xmllint`
   - for DocBook 5.x you can validate against using some other tools. See https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.0/ch03.html

**NOTE 1**: if you are using DocBook 5.x and trying to validate against RelaxNG AND Schematron schemas take into account this information: https://superuser.com/questions/741957/validating-docbook-5-documents-against-both-relaxng-and-schematron

**NOTE 2**: don't forget that there are 2 forms of correctness of `xml` files: well-formedness (correctness against XML specification) and validness (correct against specific XML vocabulary).